# Android - sign-in with google+ without GooglePlayServices

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus, google-play-services

To authenticate with Google+ on Android, Google has instructions for doing it with their Google Play Services library, yet on the web and on iOS these definitely do not have Google Play Services available but are able to authenticate with Google+.

How would Google+ authentication be implemented on Android if GooglePlayServices are not available? Similarly, Facebook has a webview based authentication subroutine if the user does not have Facebook installed, so I am curious how it works for Google+

Comment: You can easily implement using Spring for Android social, but if you want you can try https://github.com/GabiAxel/spring-social-google

Comment: @betorcs can you show me an example of an app (mobile or otherwise) that uses that library?

Comment: I don't know anyone, i only found it googling and I saw it implements G+ through spring social. I've already used spring social to implement 4shared OAuth and it was great.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly (it has been some time since I implemented them) Google+, Twitter, Facebook, etc. use OAuth as an authentication (sign-in) mechanism.  As you mentioned this is usually done in the form of a web page, through a WebView.  If I have some time later I will update with links, and an example.

UPDATE:
I haven't actually done the steps, but a quick overview of them, and it should be what are you are looking for [iOS access Google Services](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/accessing-google-services-using-the-oauth-2-0-protocol/).  The process should be the same/similar for Android/Web/etc.